# How to create an object with just one variable, which can be one of two data types?

Tags: java, object, variable-assignment, conventions

I want to create an object which  holds just one variable, but that variable can be one of two specific data types. How would I do this?

I was thinking just giving it an Object (generic) variable and then doing checks to see if the given parameters where the right classes.

But then I tried creating an empty object 'x' and then two more objects 'a' and 'b' which extended the first. Which seems to compile okay.

For example:

```
x variable = new a(); // okay

x variable2 = new b(); // okay

x variable3 = "hello"; // not okay, since it is a String.
```

Is there a 'right' way of doing this? I don't particularly like my second method since leaves me with an empty class file and the first method seems a bit clunky.

EDIT:

In the first method mentioned above the class would look a bit like this:

```
public class x{
    Object var;

    public x(Object var1){
        if (var1.getClass() == a.class || var1.getClass() == b.class){
            this.var = var1;
        }
    }

}
```

I could also just create different constructors for each combination of data type parameters, like so:

```
public class x {
     Object var;

     public x(a var1){
         this.var = var1;
     }

     public x(b var1){
         this.var = var1;
     }

}
```

The second method uses 3 different classes:

```
public class x{
//empty

}

public class a extends x{
   // some fields
   // constructors
}

public class b extends x{
   // some fields
   // constructors
}
```

EDIT2 - Some more background to the problem:

I have an object 'z', which needs to hold two variables (worth mentioning). These variables could be  of type 'a', 'a' or 'a', 'b' or 'b', 'a' or 'b', 'b'. It's just the way my program is. I then wanted to create a new data type which can be 'a' or 'b' in order to simplify the 'z' object so it is just always two 'x' variables (where either could be 'a' or 'b').

I could always create two 'a' variables and two 'b' variables in the object 'z' and leave 2 null when initializing them, but that seemed like a poor style.

In my program there is an ArrayList of objects of type 'z'.

each z variable has 2 variables. Each variable can be either an object of type a say, or an integer (the mystery type b) which refers to an index in the array ultimately to another z variable.

if you keep following the trail of z variables you will eventually reach a p variable, which is the base case sort of.

Comment: It doesn't sound right, to have a single variable to hold two different types of data. Don't you actually need to fields instead?

Comment: I think you should show us the actual class you want to create.

Comment: I could do that, but then one of the fields would always be null (empty) and I'd have to include extra code to select the right one based on the current state of the program in the body of the program. I think it's called encapsulation? Where you want to make your objects easily usable by any program? Not sure :P.

Comment: you have to tell us why you cannot do something like this: `a variableA = new a();`, `b variableB = new b();` and `int c = 3;`

Comment: Another edit added to give some background.

Answer (score 2):

This task is what class inheritance is for; you should select or write a class or interface that represents the things that the data types have in common, and the variable should be of that type. The data types should inherit from (implement) the supertype.

Comment: Could you provide an example maybe? Thanks.

Comment: @GregCawthorne java.swing has some good examples. JComponent represents the things all components have in common. Its subclasses represent the features of specific components.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for Generics.

```
public class DataStorage<T>
{
   private T data;
   public DataStorage(final T data)
   {
      this.data = data;
   }
   public T getData()
   {
      return this.data;
   }
}

DataStorage<a> aData = new DataStorage<a>(new a());
DataStorage<b> bData = new DataStorage<b>(new b());
DataStorage<Integer> intData = new DataStorage<Integer>(new Integer(3));
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat suggestion. Although I'm not sure how this functionally differs from the first method that I suggested in the OP (which the uses of the Object data type)? Since seems to accept ANY data type unless you where to include checks. I may be wrong though.

Comment: You have type safety. You can do something like this: `Integer intValue = intData.getData();` without any casts.

Comment: I don't think I need type safety. Unless casting is an expensive process and this will reduce it?